# I am unable to access any private variable inside of the same class. Anyone know why I cannot access the double "job"?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class test
    {
        private double job = 4.2; // <-- declared it here
        job = 5.7; // Giving me an "Error   CS0103  The name 'job' does not exist in the current context."  
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }


}
```

The double variable "job" or any other variable that I create (ex: public or static) I cannot use in the class. This is happening in Visual Studio 2015. I have not seen this before nor do I know what could cause this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `class` can't contain expressions directly. You need a method or something first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the variable inside the class itself. You're only allowed to change it inside a function:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class test
    {
        private double job = 4.2; // <-- declared it here

        void changeJob() {
            job = 5.7;  // Changed the line to be inside a function
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right inside the 'Test' class is declaration level. 'job=5.7' is not declaration. You can always use it inside any method, but not at declaration level.